# Sitecore Context at Event Method

Tags: events

I have an Sitecore (v8.1) Event and method that processing this event but `Sitecore.Context` is not available.

I am try to use call SiteContextSwitcher but it does't help.

```
SiteContext siteContext = SiteContext.GetSite(site);
                using (new SiteContextSwitcher(siteContext))
                {
                    Sitecore.Context.SetActiveSite(site);
                    ....
}
```

What is the best option to get context in event ?

Comment: What part of the context do you need? What I can see is that you are trying to set the context site, but that will not do if you need something else. Can you give us some information on what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: @Gatogordo by legacy reason I need to have context behavior similar to when user open default(first/main) page of site.

Comment: But what do you need from the context? The site, the database, the item, ... ?

Comment: @Gatogordo I need everything

Comment: Why? Just asking because it seems like your code is coupled to that Context too much - you might be able to get the same result otherwise. So before trying SiteContextSwitcher/DatabaseSwitcher/LanguageSwitcher/... and so so: what are actually trying to do?

Comment: @Gatogordo yes I know :( it is legacy code...I can't change everything in a moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in the next way:

1. First take the current item when the event was triggered

   ```
   Item item = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;
   ```
2. Get the current site of the item :

   ```
   Sitecore.Web.SiteInfo siteInfo = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetSiteInfoList()
   .FirstOrDefault(x => item.Paths.FullPath.StartsWith(x.RootPath));

   var siteContext=Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetSite(siteInfo.Name)
   using (new SiteContextSwitcher(siteContext))
           {
              //your logic 
           }
   ```

Comment: you beat me ;) about to paste similar code

Comment: @sitecoreclimber thanks, but how to set context in this case ?

Comment: This will only get the site, not set the whole context as OP needs apparently.

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have recognized that for just switch context is not enough... set site language should be  done as well from code...

Answer (score 2):

similar to @sitecoreClimbers answer. I have written an extension method for item to do this.

Get Item from Event arguments:

```
var item = (Item)Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0);
```

Extension method of item to get siteInfo:

```
public static SiteInfo GetSiteInfo(this Item item)
    {
        var siteInfoList = Factory.GetSiteInfoList();

        SiteInfo currentSiteinfo = null;
        var matchLength = 0;
        foreach (var siteInfo in siteInfoList)
        {
            if (!item.Paths.FullPath.StartsWith(siteInfo.RootPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || siteInfo.RootPath.Length <= matchLength)
                continue;
            matchLength = siteInfo.RootPath.Length;
            currentSiteinfo = siteInfo;
        }
        return currentSiteinfo;
    }
```

Setting site context:

```
    var context = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetSite(item.GetSiteInfo().Name);
    context.SetActiveSite(item.GetSiteInfo().Name);
    using (new SiteContextSwitcher(context.Site))
    {
        //Logic
    }
```

Comment: Same comment: this will only get the site, not set the whole context as OP needs apparently

Comment: agree, updated!